# What does "killing" mean when there is no killing?

Tags: word-meaning

From the xkcd comic [The Economic Argument](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/808:_The_Economic_Argument)

[image]

What is the meaning of *killing* here? I have looked up the dictionary and the only meaning of it is making living thing dead. I think in this context, *killing* means a revolution, but I'm not sure if it is safely to use this word for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***make a killing***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+killing) is an idiomatic phrase.

It describes a situation where you become successful and make a lot of money.